# Null при при создании CardView в AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

При создание `RecyclerView` и `CardView` выходит nullpointer , почему?

```
    class CatTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public String token = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("access_token");
    TextView text;
    public String[] contractId = new String[100];



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "start");
        Log.d(TAG, token);


        String token = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("access_token");
        Log.d(TAG, token);
        DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ResponseHandler GetResponse = new BasicResponseHandler();
        HttpGet http = new HttpGet("mysite.info/api/v1.3.0/contract/getlist?access_token=" + token);

        try {

            String response = (String) hc.execute(http, GetResponse);
            Log.d(TAG, response);

            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray contracts = jobj.getJSONArray("contracts");
            String contract = contracts.getString(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < contracts.length(); i++) {
                contractId[i] = String.valueOf(contracts.get(i));
                HttpGet http2 = new HttpGet("http://bashesk.openregion.info/api/v1.3.0/contract/counters?contract_id=" + contract);
                Log.d(TAG, contractId[i]);

                try {

                    String Cresponse = (String) hc.execute(http2, GetResponse);
                    Log.d(TAG, Cresponse);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
        lLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

        RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), rowListItem);
        rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
    }
    private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(){

        List<ItemObject> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();

        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Написать обращение", "6"));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Мои обращения", "2"));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Ближайший офис", "3"));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Заказать звонок", "4"));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Позвонить в контактный центр", "5"));

        return allItems;
    }
}
```

код ошибки:

```
    03-10 18:32:09.774 30858-30858/com.example.hondle.biling E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at com.example.hondle.biling.fragments.contracts$CatTask.onPostExecute(contracts.java:185)
                                                                               at com.example.hondle.biling.fragments.contracts$CatTask.onPostExecute(contracts.java:124)
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 18:32:09.787 544-563/? E/AppErrorDialog: Failed to get ILowStorageHandle instance
```

UPD: Класс AsyncTask находится в классе фрагмента. Список описан в классе AsyncTask. Точно на какой строчке падает я незнаю, так как Debugger не работает (работаю через adb), но все связано с этим кодом:

```
            List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
        lLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

        RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), rowListItem);
        rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
```

Comment: Я точно могу сказать что в первом запросе в url необходимо добавить "http://"

Comment: Это лишь пример запрос, в реальности у меня нормальная ссылка на запрос, да и вапще проблем с запросами нет, спотыкается программа, как только создаю карточки.

Comment: Уточните нак какой именно строке падает. getActivity() null или что то другое?..

Comment: У вас задача во фрагменте описана? А список, видать, в нём же?..

Comment: Щас я ещё магический шар поспрашиваю, а вы можете пока вопрос дополнять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мой магический шар утверждает, что RecyclerView находится во фрагменте, тогда как вы в активити его найти пытаетесь. Так что ищите чрез разметку фрагмента:

```
RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)getView().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
```

А ещё лучше сделайте RecyclerView полем класса фрагмента чтобы не искать его каждый раз по ID

Comment: Печально, но это не помогло... , даже сама android studio говорит что из за getView, может выходить Null.

Comment: Может быть null, да. Делайте на это проверку. Вы не раскрываете полностью проблему и, засим, кроме описанного помочь вам решительно невозможно. У вас в разметке фрагмента вообще список есть? И эту ли разметку вы во фрагмент загрузили? А фрагмент вообще в активити добавлен? На все эти вопросы ответ известен только вам.